# Facebook - Aggregation of posts from application and action link not shown

Tags: facebook

The posts from my application on user's Facebook wall are getting aggregated. When that happens the action link on the posts disappears. Is it possible to:
1. avoid the aggregation (The posts from my app contain different text entered by the user)
2. show the action link on the posts even in case of aggregation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing this old unanswered question. Apparently this is expected Facebook behavior (or was the behavior at that time question was asked)